# Progress bar in my custom grid search using tqdm

Tags: python, tqdm

I am implementing the grid search from scratch. This is the code:

```
def custom_grid_search(x_train, latent_dimensions):
    param_grid = {
        'epochs': [1, 3, 5],
        'l_rate': [10 ** -4],
        'batch_size': [32, 64],
        'patience': [30]
    }

    grid_search = CustomGridSearchCV(param_grid)
    grid_search.fit(x_train, latent_dimensions)

    return grid_search
```

I want to print a progress bar and I often use `tqdm` for showing progress bar over loops.

This is my code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

class CustomGridSearchCV:
    def __init__(self, param_grid):
        self.param_grid = param_grid
        self.best_params_ = {}
        self.best_score_ = None
        self.grid_ = []

    def fit(self, x_train, latent_dimensions):
        ssim_scorer = my_ssim
        param_combinations = product(*self.param_grid.values())

        for params in param_combinations:
            print("CIAO")  # Never printed!
            # other code omitted...

        return self
```

But unfortunately `"CIAO"` is never printed.

I debugged those variables that is:

```
>>> param_combinations
<itertools.product object at 0x289618300>
>>> len(list(param_combinations))
6
```

If I remove `tqdm`, that is `for params in param_combinations:` it works properly. How is that?

I want to print something like

```
Combination 1/6
Combination 2/6
...
```

Comment: You've exhausted the `itertools.product` generator. Change to `param_combinations = list(product(*self.param_grid.values()))` and in loop `total=len(param_combinations))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely What does "You've exhausted the itertools.product generator" mean?

Comment: You have iterated over the elements of `product` in the `total=len(list(param_combinations)))`, so the for-loop doesn't execute (generator is already exhausted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed as Andrej Kesey noticed in their comment:

Replace

```
param_combinations = product(*self.param_grid.values())
```

with

```
param_combinations = list(product(*self.param_grid.values()))  # list
```